# Creating new Id for menu items

Tags: android, development-environment

When I use the layout view to create new menu items the default Id is @+id/item1.  When i select Browse I get a preference chooser window with the new "New ID.." window at the bottom greyed out.  What do I need to do to create a new ID?

Comment: That works great TKS. If I edit @+id/item1 to @+id/action_edit, how can I make it register in R.java?

Answer (score -1):

You can make a use of [View.generateViewId()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#generateViewId%28%29). This will generate new id for you, make sure you save it in case you need it to make your app aware of it, because they are not added in the R.java file.

```
public class ViewUtil {
private static final AtomicInteger sNextGeneratedId = new AtomicInteger(1);
public static int generateViewId() {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1){
      for (;;) {
          final int result = sNextGeneratedId.get();
          int newValue = result + 1;
          if (newValue > 0x00FFFFFF) newValue = 1; // Roll over to 1, not 0.
            if (sNextGeneratedId.compareAndSet(result, newValue)) {
                    return result;
                }
        }else{
            return View.generateViewId();
        }
    }

}
```